# Angular validators not working

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to implement angular validators inside my form following tutorials, but the validation is ignored. Here is my code:

**view**

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputLocalita" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Località</label>
  <label *ngIf="!edit" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label col-form-label-sm grey" id="inputLocalita">{{immobile.localita}}</label>
  <div *ngIf="edit" class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="inputLocalita" formControlName="localita" placeholder="Località">
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="imm.controls.localita.errors && (imm.controls.localita.dirty || imm.controls.localita.touched)">
    <p *ngIf="imm.controls.localita.errors.required">Field is required</p>
    <p *ngIf="imm.controls.localita.errors.minlength">Field must be 8 characters long</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.imm = new FormGroup({
      comune: new FormControl(),
      provincia: new FormControl(),
      comuneObj: new FormControl(),
      cap: new FormControl(),
      indirizzo: new FormControl(),
      civico: new FormControl(),
      localita: new FormControl([
        Validators.minLength(4),
        Validators.required]),
      destinazioneUso: new FormControl(),
      destinazioneUsoAltro: new FormControl(),
      destinazioneUsoPrincipale: new FormControl(),
      destinazioneUsoSecondaria: new FormControl(),

    });
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for the hints.

Comment: further comment in favor of the solution: i recommend to use a shared error handle component or use an external package from npm such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-form-validations avoid many unnecessary error handling in .html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing usage of `formControl`. While creating a custom `FormControl`, use the below syntax(see **[API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#how-to-use)** of FormControl):

```
// for single validator
customControl = new FormControl('value', Validators.maxLength(5));

// for multiple validators(with Validators.compose)
customControl = new FormControl('value', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required]));
// or(without Validators.compose)
customControl = new FormControl('value', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required]));
```

---

Changing your formGroup code to either of the below way will solve your problem:

**Option1:** Creating a formGroup without using `new FormControl()`

```
this.imm = new FormGroup({
  comune: [],
  provincia: [],
  comuneObj: [],
  cap: [],
  indirizzo: [],
  civico: [],
  localita: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required])],
  destinazioneUso: [],
  destinazioneUsoAltro: [],
  destinazioneUsoPrincipale: [],
  destinazioneUsoSecondaria: [],
});
```

**Option2:** Correct the formControl part syntax.

```
this.imm = new FormGroup({
  comune: new FormControl(),
  provincia: new FormControl(),
  comuneObj: new FormControl(),
  cap: new FormControl(),
  indirizzo: new FormControl(),
  civico: new FormControl(),
  localita: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required])),
  destinazioneUso: new FormControl(),
  destinazioneUsoAltro: new FormControl(),
  destinazioneUsoPrincipale: new FormControl(),
  destinazioneUsoSecondaria: new FormControl(),

});
```